# accessing a Class in test directory from a Class in src directory

Tags: java, maven

Hi I have tried out the following. I have source with test and src directories build using maven. I have created a class in my test folder and try to access (create objects, static methods) from a class in my src directory. But importing test class ailed to my src class.

How can I achieve this. I know its not the idea. It shouldn't be available to access class this manner. But I need to know the reason it is blocked. And way to remove that block.

Comment: Maybe it's obvious, but I just wanted to point out that this is a really bad idea. Maven restricts the access to the `test` classes for a good reason - they will not be available at runtime either, since they are packaged in different JAR files. Please rethink and consider changing the design.

Answer (score 1):

As you have said, accessing a Test class in a Src class is not a good idea.

But it is definitely possible, just ensure `src/test/java` folder is in the classpath.

If you are using Eclipse IDE, then

`right click the project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source`

ensure `src/test/java` folder is added.